# how to create a dataframe from two columns in r

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyverse

I have the following dataset:

> data.frame(trait = c("Cholesterol", "Cholesterol", "ApoB", "ApoA",
> "TRI", "TRI"), ID = c(1,2,2,1,1,2))

```
trait           ID
Cholesterol     1
Cholesterol     2
ApoB            2
ApoA            1
TRI             1
TRI             2
```

I wanna to create a further dataframe as follow:

```
trait        1     2
Cholesterol  TRUE  TRUE
ApoB         FALSE TRUE
ApoA         TRUE  FALSE
TRI          TRUE  TRUE
```

Do you know how to get this second dataframe?

Answer (score 3):

This is the typical case for `tidyr::pivot_wider()`.

`as.logical` will coerce either 1 or 2 to TRUE, and the remaining NAs are converted to FALSE because of `values_fill = FALSE`

```
library(tidyr)

df |>
    pivot_wider(names_from = ID,
                values_from = ID,
                values_fn = as.logical,
                values_fill = FALSE)

# A tibble: 4 × 3
  trait       `1`   `2`  
  <chr>       <lgl> <lgl>
1 Cholesterol TRUE  TRUE 
2 ApoB        FALSE TRUE 
3 ApoA        TRUE  FALSE
4 TRI         TRUE  TRUE
```

data

```
df <- data.frame(trait = c("Cholesterol", "Cholesterol", "ApoB", "ApoA",
                           "TRI", "TRI"),  ID = c(1,2,2,1,1,2))
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try `table`

```
(table(df) > 0) %>%
    as.data.frame() %>%
    rownames_to_column(var = "trait")
```

which gives

```
        trait     1     2
1        ApoA  TRUE FALSE
2        ApoB FALSE  TRUE
3 Cholesterol  TRUE  TRUE
4         TRI  TRUE  TRUE
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a one-liner in base R:

```r
cbind(df[1], "1" = df[[2]] == 1, "2" = df[[2]] == 2)
#>         trait     1     2
#> 1 Cholesterol  TRUE FALSE
#> 2 Cholesterol FALSE  TRUE
#> 3        ApoB FALSE  TRUE
#> 4        ApoA  TRUE FALSE
#> 5         TRI  TRUE FALSE
#> 6         TRI FALSE  TRUE
```

<sup>Created on 2023-05-28 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Answer (score 0):

Please try,

```r
df <- data.frame(trait = c("Cholesterol", "Cholesterol", "ApoB", "ApoA", "TRI", "TRI"), 
           ID = c(1,2,2,1,1,2)) %>% 
  pivot_wider(names_from = ID , values_from = ID, values_fill = FALSE) %>% 
  mutate(across(c(`1`,`2`), ~ifelse(.x==0, FALSE, TRUE)))


# A tibble: 4 × 3
  trait       `1`   `2`  
  <chr>       <lgl> <lgl>
1 Cholesterol TRUE  TRUE 
2 ApoB        FALSE TRUE 
3 ApoA        TRUE  FALSE
4 TRI         TRUE  TRUE
```